# Workflow engine for php?

Tags: php, workflow

Who knows about a "mature" workflow engine for php?.

I am looking forward to use it from an application made using symphony framework.

Thanks !

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow/usage.html is now a part of Symphony

Answer (score 1):

Could use

- http://www.ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Workflow

Answer (score 1):

If you need a state machine you can use Symfony's one
https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow/usage.html

If you need a workflow look at https://github.com/formapro/pvm.